# How to Iterate over array using async and foreach

Tags: node.js, express, async.js

I am trying to create an api that will create a group with members in expressjs. This is how it works till now:

Make a post request with a JSON object in `req.body`, using which I will create a new group. If the members array of the `req.body` object contains member id, add it to the group members array, else create a new user and then add its id to the array.

Basically an existing user just gets added, new user will be created and then added. For this I need to loop through the members array in the `req.body` and check for an object.

But the code below doesn't seem to work properly. I am getting strange results for `console.log(group_info.members);`. I am expecting this to contain objects with `id` in an array, but getting random results. Something seems to be wrong in the foreach loop. Please help me figure it out.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Group = require('../models/GroupModel');
var User = require('../models/UserModel');
var async = require("async");

router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
var group_members = [];
var group_info = req.body;

//see if a member object is sent, create user for that else just add the user id to group_members array

async.forEach(group_info.members, function (member, callback) {
    if (typeof member == "object") {
        //create new user and add the _id to members array
        var user = new User(member);
        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
            var member_object = {id: user._id};
            group_members.push(member_object);
        }).then(callback);
    } else {
        var member_object = {id: member };
        group_members.push(member_object);
        callback();
    }
}, function (err) {
    //final call back
    group_info.members = group_members; //replace the original array in request body with the new array of users
    console.log(group_info.members);
    var group = new Group(group_info);
    group.save(function (err) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        res.json(group);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: It looks like you actually want to use [`async.map`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map) instead of `forEach` which would manage the `group_members` array for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you made a mistake its [eachSeries](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) not forEach, so just replace :

```
 async.forEach(group_info.members, function (member, callback)
```

with:

```
async.eachSeries(group_info.members, function (member, callback)
```

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments **forEach** is an alias for `async` `each` API, You can read the docs [here](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each),Thank You @megawac for pointing this out.

Comment: I ended up using the async.each series. Thanks!

Comment: forEach is actually just an alias of `each` (http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)

Answer (score 1):

```
var group_members = [];
var group_info = req.body;

var todo = group_info.members.length;
var done = 0;
if(todo == 0)
{
    return saveGroup(res, group_members);
}
else
{
    group_info.members.forEach(function (member, index, array) {
       if (typeof member == "object") {
            //create new user and add the _id to members array
            var user = new User(member);
            user.save(function (err, savedObject) {
                if (err || !savedObject)
                {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                else
                {

                    var member_object = {id: savedObject._id};
                    group_members.push(member_object);
                    if(++done >= todo)
                    {
                        return saveGroup(res, group_info, group_members);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
           var member_object = {id: member };
           group_members.push(member_object);
           if(++done >= todo)
           {
                return saveGroup(res, group_info, group_members);
            }
        }
    });
}

function saveGroup(res, group_info, group_members)
{
    group_info.members = group_members; //replace the original array in request body with the new array of users
    console.log(group_info.members);
    var group = new Group(group_info);
    group.save(function (err) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        res.json(group);
    });
}
```

Comment: looks like you removed the async library all along. If I go this way, I need to handle this all in code. That was the basic idea behind using async in first place.

Comment: Use the same process (e.g todo, done) but simply call callback instead of saveGroup